# How to run PHP page in /var/www/ from /etc/crontab?

Tags: php, cron

I want to to run php page which is in root folder ***/var/www/*** in a particular time daily. My www director is 755 permission.

I am doing cron job in /etc/crontab as an admin for mysqldump. Its working fine there. But this time I want to run particular page in /etc/crontab. And I failed to make it work after spending lots of time research.

Following is what I did in /etc/crontab.

```
14 36 * * *   root /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/page.php
```

What I want is, At 14:36HOURS, I want ***/etc/crontab*** to run page ***/var/www/mysite/page.php***. And do necessary things i.e updating in mySQL database.

Comment: change `14 36` to `36 14`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta, I change time format, but I failed.

Comment: can you check cron log also check php installation path by `which php` command

Comment: PHP installation path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
36 14 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/page.php
```

The format for crontab is minutes, hours, Day of month, month, Day of week

If you want to run your cron as root, use sudo when editing cron

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the script using php from the crontab

```
36 14 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/page.php

# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)

# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)

# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR` 
sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

for more information 
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/